# NSArrayController + NSTableView : automatically save changes without Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, autosave

OK, so I'm implementing a classic scenario :

- A `NSPopupButton` with some items in it
- When the selected value changes, my `itemsArray` is updated
- The `itemsArray` is linked to an `NSArrayController`
- Each item in the `itemsArray` is an `NSMutableDictionary` (with keys : `title`,`content`)
- An `NSTableView` displays the `title`s of the `arrangedObjects` (binding)
- An `NSTextView` displays the `content` of the selected item.

Now, what I want is to automatically save any changes to the itemsArray (or itemsArray's item title/content), but without using Core Data (which I suspect might have been the best way to go about it).

I imagine it's quite a basic question this one, but honestly I've never really like Cocoa's auto-magical way of doing things... so, I need your help...

How should I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an array to a file very easily:

```
[yourArray writeToURL:someFileURL atomically:YES];
```

This will work if all the contents of the array are property list objects (i.e. they are `NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSDictionary`, `NSArray` or `NSData` objects). This is the case in your example.

You can then recreate the array using either the `arrayWithContentsOfURL:` or `initWithContentsOfURL:` methods when you load from disk.

If your model object is more complex than just an array, then you should make your model object conform to the `NSCoding` protocol. This means you need to implement the `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:` methods. You can then use the `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` classes to convert your object to and from an `NSData` representation that you can write to disk.

You should read the [Archives and Serialization Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html) for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to add a `Shared User Defaults Controller` and bind the *Controller Content Array* from the `Array Controller` to the `Shared User Defaults Controller`